# Sse IBInspectable and IB_DESIGNABLE Bug changes not show in storyboard?

Tags: xcode, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I reading this article [IBInspectable / IBDesignable](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) and flow step,But I found change not immediately rendered on storyboard.Can anyone known why?
My Xcode Version:7.1

[image]

My main code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

UIView+CornerRadius.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (CornerRadius)
@property(nonatomic ,assign) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;
@end
```

UIView+CornerRadius.m

```
#import "UIView+CornerRadius.h"

@implementation UIView (CornerRadius)

-(void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0;
}

-(CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    return  self.layer.cornerRadius;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code in Xcode, and I found that if you declare the view on storyboard as an instance of UIView+CornerRadius, it really don't work. But if you create a subclass of UIView or your UIView+CornerRadius category, and declare the view as this subclass, it will work fine.

I'll attach a screenshot to demonstrate:
[image]

Comment: Oh, the code in the category is exactly the same as yours. And you don't need to write any code in the subclass CornerView of UIView